# Typescript Record item count

Tags: typescript2.0, typescript-generics

Is it possible to find the count of items in a Typescript record?

For example something like

```
const testRecord: Record<string, string> = {
  'one': 'value1',
  'two': 'value2'
};

var length = testRecord.length;

// looking for length to be 2 but is undefined as there is no length property
```

For reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

Answer (score 45):

I've just found this answer here for the length of a javascript object which seems to work just fine:

[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

My implementation to answer the example above was:

```
const testRecord: Record<string, string> = {
    'one': 'value1',
    'two': 'value2'
  };

var length: Object.keys(testRecord).length;
// length equals 2
```

However please let me know if there is a better, more specific "Record" way to do this?

Comment: If you visualize the object, it makes very much sense to do it like you do here. I don't see this as too "hacky" if that is what you mean. Considering a Record is merely a regular Javascript object in terms of structure, I cannot imagine any better way of doing this as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not what you wanted, but there is a [Map type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that has size property.

You can use it like this:

```
let m = new Map<string, any>();
m.set('a', 1)
let one = m.get('a');
console.log('a value is: ' + one + '; size of the map is: ' + m.size);
```

Map doesn't work exactly as Object does, so take a look at differences in behaviour first:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps